# remove/change element style in jquery accordion content

Tags: jquery, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I am using jquery accordion in my application.

I am showing some links in accordion content using ul and li. The active accordion content has lot of empty space underneath the links when using ul and li.

By looking in Firebug, it shows the below style for each active accordion content.

html:

```
<div class="ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-accordion-content-active" style="height: 74px;" role="tabpanel">
```

css:

```
element.style {
   display:none;
   height:74px;
}
```

How can i remove the height or change the height according to the accordion content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setting autoHeight: false works .

```
$('#Accordion').accordion({ autoHeight: false })
```